# Bind click event to button from other form (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, binding, submit

can you please help me to bind id="submit1" btn when I clicking on id="submit2" btn?
My code:

```
<div id="newswhite">


<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post">
<textarea name="text1" class="form-control"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit1" class="btn" name="submit" value="send">
</form>


<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#submit1", function() {    
    var url = "some1.php";
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#form1").serialize(),
            success: function(data)
           {    
    $("#newswhite").load(" #newswhite >*"); 
          }
         });
    return false;
});
</script>

</div>


<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post">
<textarea name="text1" class="form-control"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit2" class="btn" name="submit" value="send">
</form>


<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#submit2", function() {    
    var url = "some2.php";
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#form2").serialize(),
            success: function(data)
           {    
    $("#newswhite").load(" #newswhite >*"); 
          }
         });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Of course individually post works ok from both forms but when I sending data from form2, cannot click to id="submit1" btn.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Call `$('#form1')[0].submit()` within the second button event handler. However note that this isn't good practice. I'd suggest you join the forms together in the HTML and have a single PHP file which handles them.

Comment: Thanks Roy, definitely works.